# C++ strings to/from file

Tags: c++, string, file

Simple question: why the following code isn't working? I would expect a string to be saved and read, but this just doesn't happen...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

static string path = "/Users/john/Desktop/file";


main() {
string a;

a = "one\n";

fstream outStream(path.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
outStream.write((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
outStream.close();

a = "two\n";

fstream inStream(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
inStream.read((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
inStream.close();

cout << a;
return 0;}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does happen?  Error message? Warning? Linker error?  Computer reboots?

Comment: When you start casting things `(char *)` then you are basically telling the compiler to shut up rather than fix the error it was telling you about. **NEVER** tell the compiler to shut up. Fix the errors correctly. Which for beginners means **do not use cast** without asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant write a string as a pointer. Either use the normal stream operators (`<<`) or use

```
outStream.write(a.c_str(), a.size());
```

Comment: Technically correct. But do you think it is the best way for a beginner (like OP) to learn to write strings to a stream? I don't I think it steers them down the wrong path in general.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.c_str()` and `.size()` in `write` as well:

```
outStream.write(a.c_str(),a.size());
```

`.length()` is also there, which returns same value as `.size()`.

But why don't you simply do this:

```
outStream << a;
```

And read it as:

```
inStream >> a;
```

Comment: Thank you! I discovered I have to use this trick even in outStream.read otherwise I get a segmentation fault. I can't use << and >> since my file doesn't contain just a string...   :D

Comment: Since the OP is obviously a noob you should add a note about the non symmetry of reading and writing a string with << and how to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

```
(char *) &a
```

is not the character string stored inside `std::string`, you're just telling the compiler to treat that arbitrary address (where the `std::string path` object is stored) as if it were characters.

```
sizeof(a)
```

will not give the length of the string in bytes: `sizeof` gives the size of objects, but the `std:string` object is the housekeeping information for your characters, not the text itself.

Use

```
outStream.write(a.c_str(), a.size());
```

or, better,

```
outStream << a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declare a a `string`, but you are trying to read and write it as if it were an array of characters.  `std::string` is not implemented as an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
outStream << a.c_str();
```

instead of

```
outStream.write((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
outStream.write((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
```

To

```
outStream.write(a.c_str(), s.size());
```